# mutt -- multiaccount support

Tags: mutt

Can anybody help me with mutt configuration?

I need to configure mutt to support mutiple accounts the same time.

At this moment my config file for personal email looks like this:

```
~ $ cat ~/.mutt/personal

set imap_user = «%personal_email%@gmail.com»
set imap_pass = «%personal_email_pass%»
set smtp_url = «smtps://%personal_email%@smtp.gmail.com:465/»
set smtp_pass = «%personal_email_pass%»
set from = «%personal_email%»
set realname = «%username%»
set hostname = gmail.com
set folder = «imaps://%personal_email%@imap.gmail.com:993»
set spoolfile = «imaps://%personal_email%@imap.gmail.com/INBOX»
set postponed = «imaps://%personal_email%@imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/Drafts»
set record = «imaps://%personal_email%@imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/Sent Mail»
```

"~/.mutt/work" looks the same way, except the values of "%personal_email%" and "%personal_email_pass%", of course.

"~/.muttrc" looks like this:

```
~ $ cat ~/.muttrc

source «~/.mutt/personal»

macro index <f2> '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source ~/.mutt/personal<enter><change-folder>!<enter>'
macro index <f3> '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source ~/.mutt/work<enter><change-folder>!<enter>'
```

When I press F2 or F3 mutt really changes an account, but when I'm trying to change mailbox (via 'c' -> '?') it opens a mailbox of the first account (in my case "personal") even when the current account is "work".

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: You might have better luck with the mutt user mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

Some trickery with hooks. You might want to think twice about storing passwords into `.muttrc`. At least take care to use application specific passwords instead of your main Google account password when you do something as insecure as this.

```
# Gmail account passwords and usernames
set my_gmail_user1 = "<account 1, without @gmail or anything>"
set my_gmail_user2 = "<account 2, without @gmail or anything>"
set my_gmail_pass1 = "<password, hopefully an app-specific one>"  
set my_gmail_pass2 = "<password, hopefully an app-specific one>"  

# Account hooks
account-hook . "unset imap_user ; unset imap_pass"
account-hook "imaps://$my_gmail_user1@imap.gmail.com" "\
    set imap_user = $my_gmail_user1 \
            imap_pass = $my_gmail_pass1"
account-hook "imaps://$my_gmail_user2@imap.gmail.com" "\
    set imap_user = $my_gmail_user2 \
            imap_pass = $my_gmail_pass2"

# Gmail folders
set folder          = imaps://$my_gmail_user1@imap.gmail.com/
mailboxes           = +INBOX =[Gmail]/Drafts =[Gmail]/'Sent Mail' =[Gmail]/Spam =[Gmail]/Trash
set spoolfile       = +INBOX
folder-hook         imaps://$my_gmail_user1@imap.gmail.com/ "\
    set folder      = imaps://$my_gmail_user1@imap.gmail.com/ \
        spoolfile   = +INBOX \
        postponed   = +[Gmail]/Drafts \
        record      = +[Gmail]/'Sent Mail' \
        from        = 'First User Real Name <$my_gmail_user1@gmail.com> ' \
        realname    = 'First User Real Name' \
        smtp_url    = smtps://$my_gmail_user1@smtp.gmail.com \
        smtp_pass   = $my_gmail_pass1"
set folder          = imaps://$my_gmail_user2@imap.gmail.com/
mailboxes           = +INBOX =[Gmail]/Drafts =[Gmail]/'Sent Mail' =[Gmail]/Spam =[Gmail]/Trash
set spoolfile       = +INBOX
folder-hook         imaps://$my_gmail_user2@imap.gmail.com/ "\
    set folder      = imaps://$my_gmail_user2@imap.gmail.com/ \
        spoolfile   = +INBOX \
        postponed   = +[Gmail]/Drafts \
        record      = +[Gmail]/'Sent Mail' \
        from        = 'First User Real Name <$my_gmail_user2@gmail.com> ' \
        realname    = 'First User Real Name' \
        smtp_url    = smtps://$my_gmail_user2@smtp.gmail.com \
        smtp_pass   = $my_gmail_pass2"
```

Now all there is left to it is to fire up mutt, then hit <kbd>y</kbd> and select the folder for an account you want.

If you want more secure setup, your favorite search engine can tell you how to secure IMAP/POP passwords for Mutt with PGP. Realname/from is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I'm interested in using different accounts based on recipient. Looks like you can do this with `send-hook`s, but how to set things back after the mail is sent?

Comment: While this answer might illustrate how to setup multiple accounts with mutt the TO already accomplished this task. So this does not in any way answer the question: "Why does mutt offer to open a mailbox (by typing "c") belonging to the *first* account regardless of the fact that the second account is active."

Answer (score 1):

I am using mutt in a similar way and also noticed that mutt does not offer to open right away a mailbox belonging to the currently active account (not being the first one) when just typing `c`.

You may, however, **type `c` then `=` and `TAB` *thrice* and you will be shown the mailboxes of the currently active account. Hitting `TAB` again will even allow you to switch between your different accounts' mailboxes.**

So far, AFAICT, within mutt there lies no solution (yet) to your question "Why does mutt - when typing `c` - offer to open a mailbox belonging to the first account, regardless of the fact that another/second account is active.".

My best guess is, it's either a deliberate design choice or a bug no one cared to fix yet. Using [neo]mutt's sidebar might also alleviate the UX.